# Ipv4 ClientIp on extractClientIp -> akka-http

Tags: java, akka, akka-http

How can i get the **ipv4** client ip in `akka-http` under `java`?
On my `createRoute` method, i try:

```
return extractClientIP(clientIp -> {
            Optional<InetAddress> optAdd = clientIp.getAddress();
            return complete(optAdd.get().getClass().getName());
        });
```

but i got `java.net.Inet6Address` instance instead `java.net.Inet4Address` instance.

`request.getHeader("Remote-Address")` returns ipv6 too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a preference for your Akka-HTTP app to use IPv4. That should be done by setting the following JVM option:

```
java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

If you're using SBT:

```
javaOptions += "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

Related question:
https://superuser.com/questions/453298/how-to-force-java-to-use-ipv4-instead-ipv6